# remove a portion of string values in column

Tags: python, pandas

```
START=20220605104039.163068
START=20220605104045.818461
START=20220605104051.500539
START=20220605104053.444575
```

```
sep='='
df['START'].str.split(sep,[1])
```

result

```
0        NaN
1        NaN
2        NaN
3        NaN
4        NaN
          ..
748122   NaN
748123   NaN
748124   NaN
748125   NaN
748126   NaN
```

I want to remove a portion START= before values, but got null result.
I need result like this

```
20220605104053.444575
20220605104045.818461
20220605104053.444575
```

any code or suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Because the second parameter of [`str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) takes an integer, not a list:

> n: int, default -1 (all)
>
> Limit number of splits in output. None, 0 and -1 will be interpreted as return all splits.

```
df['START'].str.split('=', 1)
```

output:

```
0    [START, 20220605104039.163068]
1    [START, 20220605104045.818461]
2    [START, 20220605104051.500539]
3    [START, 20220605104053.444575]
Name: START, dtype: object
```

If you only want the second part, slice afterwards:

```
df['START'].str.split('=', 1).str[1]
```

or use `str.replace`:

```
df['START'].str.replace('START=', '', regex=False)
# or to ensure only removing "START=" at the beginning
df['START'].str.replace('^START=', '', regex=True)
```

or `str.extract`:

```
df['START'].str.extract('^START=(.*)', expand=False)
```

output:

```
0    20220605104039.163068
1    20220605104045.818461
2    20220605104051.500539
3    20220605104053.444575
Name: START, dtype: object
```